# CSV line string search fail

Tags: csv, eol

--Python 3.5.4, Windows 7--

I have a log file that contains many lines like the following:
"08/23/2018,07.12.59,AM, -7020001 -20783 -5B7E95C6, 200 being programmed, , Standby: P, CFH – No Limit: P, CFH – No TT: P, CFH – Flame On: P, CFH - Norm: P, Lockout: P, Power cycle: P, Lockout reset: P, CFH 2: P, Valve Question:Pass, Print:Pass"

The following code does not find the "Print:Pass":

```
if (os.path.isfile(localFile)):
   with open(localFile, 'rt', newline='\r\n') as csvfile: 
        lutFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
          for line in lutFile:
             if ('Print:Pass' in line):
```

I have tried opening the file with different newline definitions, 'rU' instead of 'rt' and even tried dialect='excel' in the csv.read call. The LiClipse debugger shows the line broken apart correctly by delimiter with the last string being "Print:Pass". The Qt code that generates the log file is supposed to use a "\r\n" EOL but I have not been able to verify this. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe that last string is " Print:Pass" with a space at the beginning instead of your expected "Print:Pass"

Comment: And that would be the magic answer(thank you!) So are you saying that the string I'm searching for must match the entire csv.reader delimited string?

Comment: Correct, but looks like your data is not uniform, some places you have just comma, some others you have comma space

Comment: The Qt code that generates the log file gets it's data from other test equipment so the strings are currently not uniform. I'm kind of surprised the string search fails as the "in" key word makes you think the search is more like a strcspn() call in C. Thanks again for the help.